# How to send letters of reference (LOR) online?

Tags: application

I am applying to university very soon and my LORs are already ready. I will send my application online. But how do I send LORs? Do I have to get my recommenders sign the letter and scan them and add it to my application? Or do I need to write a LOR in an electronic version with signuture pasted? I would be very glad if anyone answeers back.
Thanks)

Comment: What are the instructions from the universities you are applying to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I have to sign a recommendation letter that will be submitted online?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61649/do-i-have-to-sign-a-recommendation-letter-that-will-be-submitted-online)

Comment: Also: [Scanned Letter of Recommendation versus Saved as PDF](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/80125/68109)

Comment: Usually your letter writer will send the letter separately so that you can't read it. They will be able to follow the instructions provided by the university.

Comment: Assuming confidentiality here, generally the application system will send a link to a form where recommenders can upload their letters (without you having to see them).  Or in some cases they will have to e-mail their letters to a person on the admissions committee.